# How to load Web font for Power BI Embeded?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We need to provide the font via CDN as some client does not have it.

The report is in `iframe`, so any attempt at the hosting page is not working.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work because of cross-domain policy

Comment: @s_king Understood that. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Tried out adding Kenia google font in my embedded report in this way. LMK if your requirement is something else

Comment: @Sai did adding the google font to your application work?

Comment: Yes, Refer to the solution below and the snapshot of embedded report with the font

Answer (score -1):

If we want to change the font that it is present in client library, we can use `applyTheme` api and change the font.
But if you want to change the font that is not present in client, there is no possibile way to do with Api. But you can achieve this by setting custom theme in PowerBI Desktop. Follow below steps.

1. Download the font family to your local machine.
2. Create a theme.json file.

   {"name":"Custom","textClasses":{"label":{"fontFace":"Kenia"},"callout":{"fontFace":"'Kenia'"},"title":{"fontFace":"'Kenia'"},"header":{"fontFace":"'Kenia'"}}}
3. In 'View' section of PowerBI Desktop, browse for themes and select the theme.json folder and theme will be applied.
4. Now publish the report in powerbiservice and you can embed the report.
   [image: Sample]

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/apply-report-themes
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes#report-theme-json-file-format
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes

Comment: Thanks. Does this require the client to have that font installed in the first place?

Comment: If we are sharing PowerBI Report and if the client is opening in PowerBI Desktop client should have the font installed. If you are embedding the report and sharing embedded report then it's not required for the client to have the font. It will work

Comment: How does the browser know where to download the font? You never provided powerbi with a URL to a google font or another font server. This can never work in the embedded report unless you install the font locally.